# How would I get CMD or something to find a duplicate copy of a file that is in another directory and delete it?

Tags: file, filesystems, backup, copy-paste

I have a backup box now and before I would just make manual backups and move those backups to another internal drive in my computer. Now that I have a proper backup box I transferred my main backup to it. The issue is that I have a bunch of older backups and some of them are really old like maybe a year + old.

What I want to do is put all those backups into a single folder and compare those files with my current backup and have it so that any file that is the same (size, date modified, name, etc) in both of them to be deleted from the old backup but keep it in the current backup. The issue is that the files won't be in the same location as they are in the current backup.

For example say File A exists in A:\Folder but the same file in the old backup exists in B:\Folder\Folder\"Random Folder Name". They're the same file but in different locations, so how would I get something like CMD to find and delete the one in the B:\ drive?

Comment: There is freeware around that will do this quite well....Perhaps search around on the 'net

Comment: Care to share it? Because I've been looking for awhile now and I can't find something that will do the trick. :/

Comment: I haven't looked for years, but check this out http://www.snapfiles.com/downloadfind.php?action=s&ref=2&st=duplicate

Comment: Ah alright, will do. Thanks :)